# XML request in jQuery gets ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have build a webpage that focuses a lot on an XML file to populate it. Now I generated a second one for some additional tasks. Unfortunatly, everytime I try to parse it, it dows not succeed.

I am using very simple code to demonstrate the problem. I stripped the function, so everything it does is writing strings into the browser console.

Once I excecute this code, all I get is "pos1, pos3, pos4"
So the success function is not even excecuted. I know this sounds like a dumb question, but it is really hard for me, to find my mistake right now.

```
function insertFirstBeginnerQuestion(){

console.log('pos1');

$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/questions.xml',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {console.log('pos2');},
    error: function(){console.log('pos3');},

});

console.log('pos4');

};
```

Comment: `error` callback has 3 arguments, try to log them and see what's happening `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }`

Comment: That did it. Unfortunately, the xml file was not valid. some tag wasn't closed properly. Thanks for the tipp with the error message!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying it in server? Your code works for me and loads the xml properly. GET is a HTTP method, so you have to deploy this in a server and access using http protocol. Otherwise this will give you 404 error while trying to load the xml file.